# Genus bei Verwendung heterogener Termini

Tags: gender

Welches Genus haben Nomen aus einer anderen Fremdsprache?
Zum Beispiel das Wort `application` aus dem Englischen wird im Deutschen oft abgekürzt als `App` verwendet.

Welches Genus hat dieser Begriff?

> die App (f.)

Man verwendet also das Genus der Übersetzung `die Anwendung` oder

> das App (n.)

Hier wird das Genus aus der Fremdsprache übernommen.

Interessanterweise verwende ich hier oft den Begriff `Genus` (lat.) und dort übernehme ich das Geschlecht der Fremdsprache.
Das ist mir bei vielen lateinischen Begriffen aufgefallen.
Liege ich hier richtig, wenn ich bei lateinischen Begriffen immer das Genus aus dem Lateinischen übernehme?

Comment: Ok, das ist schon mal interessant. Ich lese also mehr heraus, dass es eher Unregelmäßigkeiten gibt als Regeln. Jedoch fallen mir meine o.g. Vermutung keine Gegenbeispiele ein.

Comment: Und habe ich mit meiner zweiten Vermutung recht?

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt hier m. W. keine fixen Regeln. Wenn es in der Fremdsprache Geschlechter gibt (Französisch, z. B.), werden diese manchmal übernommen; es kann aber auch leicht übertrieben wirken, konsequent „der Front National“ oder „die Place de la Concorde“ zu sagen.

Beim Englischen ist die Sache schwieriger, weil es hier kein Genus im eigentlichen Sinn gibt. Wenn das Wort einem bestimmten Schema ähnelt, wird gerne dessen Geschlecht genommen, ebenso, wenn man dafür ein bestimmtes deutsches Wort substituieren kann. Aber, wie gesagt, fixe Regeln gibt es nicht, und es entscheidet letztlich nur der Sprachgebrauch.

Im österr. Deutsch scheint der sächliche Artikel vielfach bevorzugt zu werden, auch wenn man in D z. B. weibliches oder männliches Geschlecht verwendet (das/die Cola, das/die E-Mail, das/der Keks.) Warum? Keiner weiß es :)

Comment: Moment, in Ö sagt man "Das Cola"? O_O

Comment: @nixda: Ja. Beispiel: Das österreichische Unternehmen Red Bull hat auch Cola im Sortiment. Und so sieht die Werbung dafür aus: http://www.basg.gv.at/uploads/media/Cola_Red_Bull.JPG

Comment: Ja. Das Cola, das Fanta, usw. (aber der Almdudler :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe die Beobachtung gemacht, dass häufig (aber nicht immer) der Begriff ins Deutsche übersetzt wird, und dann der Artikel des deutschen Wortes für das Wort aus der Fremdsprache verwendet wird.

Daher:

> Die Firewall - Die Feuermauer
>   Die E-Mail - Die elektronische Post
>   Der Star - Der Stern
>   Der Place de la Concorde - Der Platz der Einigkeit
>   Die Front National - Die nationale Front
>   Das Event - Das Ereignis
>   Die Playstation - Die Spielstation

Der Nachteil dieser Methode: Sie funktioniert nur wenn es auch ein deutsches Wort dafür gibt. Das ist nicht immer der Fall. Bei Wörtern wie Yoga, Ayurveda, Dim Sum, Mahjong, Tacheles oder Zen wird's schwierig.

Comment: Das funktioniert aber nicht immer, und auch nicht immer für den ganzen deutschen Sprachraum. Heißt es zB der oder das Weblog? Warum die Email, wenn es doch "der" Brief heißt? In andere Fällen gibt es das Wort schon im Deutschen, wenn auch vielleicht mit anderer Bedeutung, wie zB die Station, da tut man sich leicht. Manchmal hilft auch das natürliche Geschlecht, wie zB bei der Star.

Comment: @Ingmar: Die Station - der Bahnhof. :) Pizza quattro stationi: Pizza 4 Bahnhöfe (siehe Monopoly). Viele sagen auch "der Event". Und Tacheles ist ja wohl ein deutsches Wort. Das Tacheles, übrigens. Wir gingen oft in das Tacheles.

Comment: @userunknown: Tacheles ist Hebräisch, es gibt kein gleichbedeutendes deutsches Wort. In hebräischer Schrift: »תכלס«. Das sind (von rechts nach links) die Buchstaben ת-Taw (steht für den Konsonanten t), כ-Kaph (Steht für einen Laut, der klanglich eine Mischung aus 1/3 »k« und 2/3 »ch« ist, ähnlich der in Tirol verbreiteten Variante des »ch«), ל-Lamed (l) und ס-Samech (s). Also: »tchls«. Die Hebräische Schrift hat keine Zeichen für Vokale, die muss man sich dazudenken. In Hebräisch ist sowohl die Aussprache "Tachles" als auch "Tacheles" zu finden (beides mit einem aus der Kehle kommenden »ch«).

Comment: Mein ÖWB sagt Tacheles sei ein Pluralwort, daher die T.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast; Tacheles mag aus dem Hebräischen kommen oder dem Jiddischen - es steht jedenfalls im Duden, ist also jetzt auch ein Deutsches Wort. Ein anderes, gleichbedeutendes Wort wäre Klartext. Abgeleitet von dem Ausdruck gab es in den letzten 2 Jahrzehnten (und womöglich davor) in der Berliner Oranienburger Straße das Tacheles, ein Kunst- und Kulturzentrum.